# Developing webpage for mobile, resolution choice

Tags: html, iphone, mobile, resolution, responsive

I am developing a page that needs to be able to view on a mobile platform. What resolution should be the standard for this? I live in Norway, and there are mostly iPhones and HTC-phones on the market here.

Any ideas?

Comment: The webpage contains several pdf-files too, that needs to be scaled down from the original computer-fullscreen-ones.

Comment: http://jquerymobile.com/ might work for you. I dont know about the pdf's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to accommodate more than just iPhone and HTC resolutions, I would consider incorporating responsive design into your site. Google also [recommends](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/responsive-design-harnessing-power-of.html) it.